# Google Play Services out of date in Android Emulator

Tags: android, google-play-services, emulation

I have an android emulator with Marshmallow and Google Apis.
For some reason the Google Play Services got stuck in release 8.1.85 and it doesn't get updated.
My app uses the 8.3 release in Android Studio Gradle:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.3.0'
```

When the app starts it detects it is out of date so the "update dialog" appears. Clicking on update it does nothing. I get this log:

```
12-21 12:21:46.369 3516-3516/app.pack.com W/GooglePlayServicesUtil: Google Play services out of date.  Requires 8298000 but found 8185470
12-21 12:21:46.548 3516-3541/app.pack.com W/EGL_emulation: eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
12-21 12:21:46.548 3516-3541/app.pack.com W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xabff10c0, error=EGL_SUCCESS
12-21 12:21:46.685 3516-3541/app.pack.com W/EGL_emulation: eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
12-21 12:21:46.686 3516-3541/app.pack.com W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xb3f09320, error=EGL_SUCCESS
12-21 12:21:47.065 3516-3541/app.pack.com W/EGL_emulation: eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
12-21 12:21:47.065 3516-3541/app.pack.com W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xb3f3f240, error=EGL_SUCCESS
12-21 12:21:50.302 3516-3541/app.pack.com E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0xab7980b0
12-21 12:21:56.326 3516-3516/app.pack.com E/SettingsRedirect: Can't redirect to app settings for Google Play services
12-21 12:21:56.333 3516-3541/app.pack.com E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0xab796d70
12-21 12:21:56.339 3516-3541/app.pack.com D/OpenGLRenderer: endAllStagingAnimators on 0xa19fa980 (RippleDrawable) with handle 0xb12c9ac0
12-21 12:21:56.366 3516-3516/app.pack.com W/GooglePlayServicesUtil: Google Play services out of date.  Requires 8298000 but found 8185470
12-21 12:21:56.432 3516-3541/app.pack.com W/EGL_emulation: eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
12-21 12:21:56.432 3516-3541/app.pack.com W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xad71b0c0, error=EGL_SUCCESS
12-21 12:21:56.793 3516-3541/app.pack.com W/EGL_emulation: eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
12-21 12:21:56.793 3516-3541/app.pack.com W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xb3f3f920, error=EGL_SUCCESS
12-21 12:22:00.027 3516-3541/app.pack.com E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0xab798e40
```

Comment: Have you tried updating your emulator images in the SDK Manager, then creating a fresh AVD?

Comment: Yes, several times. I got a couple updates lately, I think. I have also created new AVDs but they are always created with 8.1.85

Comment: my AVD's have 8.1.85 and my app needs 8.3.0, how to update the AVD ?

Comment: I finally got a sdk update that has 8.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is solution: using AVD image with build-in Google Play Services. It will enable you to use Google Services including Google Play. Also you will be able update it without re-creating AVD image.

Open AVD manager and choose create new device. You should use device definition with play store icon.

[image: 1]

Then choose system image for it. You should choose one with **Google Play** and **NOT** with Google API.

[image: 2]

Then launch new device.

[image: 3]

You can update Play Services as shown on screenshot, or manually on device..

[image: 4]

Answer (score 1):

The solution I've tried for this issue before is to change:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.3.0'
```

to

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.+'
```

Sometimes, what is reflected on the gradle is not the actual version and by putting `+` the app will automatically use the latest version available.